# Keep plot from disappearing after finishing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to use blitting in matplotlib, but when the blitting finishes the plotted data disappears.
I want to be able to use the data that was plotted last.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
(ln,) = ax.plot(list(range(0, 100)), [1, 2, 3, 6]*25, animated=True)

plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(0.1)
bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
for j in range(100):

    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    ln.set_ydata(np.array([j/20, 0, j/20, 0]*25))
    ax.draw_artist(ln)
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
plt.show() # Keeps window open indefinitely
```

During plot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4115.png

After plotting is finished (plot disappears):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Cjn.png